# how to implement multiple consumable products in-app purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I've successfully implemented one consumable product, however i have no clue to to implement multiple consumable products. Id like to addd more ProductIdentifiers like com.lalala.20batteries, com.lalala.30batteries

can anyone please give me some guides

here is my code for the single consumable product

```
@interface ViewController () <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>

@end

@implementation ViewController


#define ProductIdentifier @"com.lalala.10batteries"

- (IBAction)taps10batteries{
   NSLog(@"User requests to get 10 batteries");

   if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
      NSLog(@"User can make payments");

      SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:ProductIdentifier]];
      productsRequest.delegate = self;
      [productsRequest start];

   }
   else{
      NSLog(@"User cannot make payments due to parental controls");

   }
}



- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
   SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
   int count = [response.products count];
   if(count > 0){
      validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
      NSLog(@"Products Available!");
      [self purchase:validProduct];
   }
   else if(!validProduct){
      NSLog(@"No products available");

   }
}


- (IBAction)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
   SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];

   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];


}



- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
   NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
   for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions){
      if(transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored){
         //called when the user successfully restores a purchase
         NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");

         [self get10Batteries];
         [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
         break;
      }
   }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
   for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
      switch(transaction.transactionState){
         case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");

            break;
         case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

            [self get10Batteries]; 
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");
            break;
         case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
         case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

            if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
               NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
               //the user cancelled the payment ;(
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
      }
   }
}


- (void)get10Batteries{

    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *cloudstore1 = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];

   //load cloud integer
   coins = [cloudstore1 doubleForKey:@"yo" ];



   coins = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                       integerForKey:@"com.lalala.10batteries"];
   coins += 10;
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:coins
                                              forKey:@"com.lalala.10batteries"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];



  _coinLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)coins];



   //save icloud

   [cloudstore1 setDouble:coins forKey:@"yo"];

   [cloudstore1 synchronize];


}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

   NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *cloudstore1 = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
   _coinLabel.text = [cloudstore1 stringForKey:@"yo" ];


   NSUserDefaults *coinsdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];




   if([coinsdefaults objectForKey:@"com.lalala.10batteries"] != nil) {

      coins = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"com.lalala.10batteries"];

      coins = [coinsdefaults integerForKey:@"com.lalala.10batteries"];

       _coinLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)coins];



   }



}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to implement multiple consumable products? Please do some research and put forth the effort to try, and we'll be happy to help you debug.

Comment: i have done a lot but i still have no clue. for example, the tutorial from ray wenderlich. they use "NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                              @"com.razeware.inapprage.drummerrage",
                              @"com.razeware.inapprage.itunesconnectrage",
                              @"com.razeware.inapprage.nightlyrage",

                              nil];"  i just don't know how to apply in my case. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can easily support multiple products, just like it supports one... 
First of all, declare your other product IDs just like you did with one:

```
#define ProductIdentifier1 @"com.lalala.10batteries"
#define ProductIdentifier2 @"com.lalala.20batteries"
```

Then, create a `loadAllProducts` method, which is exactly like the `taps10batteries` method, except you declare your `SKProductsRequest` with ALL of the product IDs, just like you did with one:

```
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:ProductIdentifier1, ProductIdentifier2, nil]];
```

Unless you prefer loading each product individually, then you'll need to create a method for each product, i.e. `taps20batteries` and you can ignore the next part of my answer...

The callback method can return multiple products like it can return one. Handle the response as you see fit, just like you did with one:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
   int count = [response.products count];
   if(count > 0){
       _products = [response.products sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) { //sort all products by price
            NSDecimalNumber *first = [(SKProduct*)a price];
            NSDecimalNumber *second = [(SKProduct*)b price];
            return [second compare:first];
        }];
       for (SKProduct *product in _products) {
         NSLog(@"Product Available: %@", product.productIdentifier);
         //do something with the product..
         //perhaps gather the products into an array and present it somehow to the user so s/he can select what to buy?
       }
   }
   else {
   NSLog(@"No products available");

   }
}
```

If you want a full implementation that you can use, try [this one](https://github.com/saturngod/IAPHelper)

Comment: hehe, wrote it at the same time. Mine has sorting by price :P

Comment: Yes @Jaro , sorting by price is definitely a nice touch, I'll add it to my answer. Sorry for stealing your thunder ;)

Answer (score 1):

see the line where you create SKProductsRequest object:

```
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:ProductIdentifier]];
```

NSSet is a bag with objects inside unsorted and only one kind of allowed inside the bag (no dupes).

All you have to do is change it like this:

```
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:
                                  @"com.blahblah.unlockall",
                                  @"com.blahblah.sounds",
                                  @"com.blahblah.alarms",
                                  @"com.blahblah.wallpapers",
                                  nil]];
```

then u should have a custom wrapper class (CustomIAPHelper) as in the tutorial.

in view controller let's say you have a tableView then the code follows like this:

```
- (void)reload {
    _products = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [CustomIAPHelper sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    [[CustomIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {

            // Sort the products array (by price)
           _products = [products sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
                NSDecimalNumber *first = [(SKProduct*)a price];
                NSDecimalNumber *second = [(SKProduct*)b price];
                return [second compare:first];
            }];

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
        [activity stopAnimating];
        [activity setHidden:YES];
    }];
}
```

remember to setup and implement iAPHelper's protocol methods.